# How to calculate margin of error for a combination of unequal samples?

Tags: statistics

Say I have a population which I've divided into 7 groups by some criterion. The groups have different (known) sizes and different (expected) distributions. I've taken a differently sized sample from each group. I then combined these 7 subsamples into a single large supersample. How do I calculate the MOE for that supersample?

Being a beginner in statistics, I've been using [this site](http://www.raosoft.com/samplesize.html) to calculate MOE. Under "Alternate scenarios" I can enter sample size, population and expected distribution for each subsample separately and get the MOE. But I don't know how to get from those subsample MOEs to the supersample MOE. Is there a simple function I can use for this?

Comment: What you're describing is "stratified sampling". Searching the site for that term will give you several results, but perhaps none that exactly answer your question. The formulas are a bit more complex, but usually not too bad. Is your survey question about a binary yes-no question, a continuous value (eg, age), or something more complex?

Comment: @DavidLukeThiessen Thanks. It is a binary value.

Answer (score 2):

It is a general property that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent random variables, then the "variance" of the sum equals the sum of the variances: $V[X_1+X_2] = V[X_1] + V[X_2]$. I will assume that the samples you take from each group (aka, strata) are independent. That is, the individuals you pick from one group do not affect which individuals you will choose from any of the other groups.

Suppose the total size of the population is $N$, the sizes of each of the 7 groups are $N_i, i=1,\ldots,7$, $\sum N_i = N$, you take a sample of size $n_i$ from each strata, the observed proportion of individuals who answer "yes" (or "1", or whatever) in the $i$th group is $\hat{p}_i$, and the proportion who answer "no" is $\hat{q}_i$.

Then the estimate of the population proportion who answer "yes" is

$$
\hat{p} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{7}N_{i}\hat{p}_i
$$

The estimated variance of this estimate is

$$
\hat{V}[\hat{p}] = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^{7} N_{i}^2\hat{V}[\hat{p}_i]\\
= \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^{7} N_{i}^2 \left(1- \frac{n_i}{N_i} \right)\frac{\hat{p}_i\hat{q}_i}{n_i - 1}\\
$$

And the approximate margin of error for a 95% confidence level is 1.96 times the square root of the variance,

$$
MOE_{95}(\hat{p}) = 1.96 * \sqrt{\hat{V}[\hat{p}] }
$$

Searching for "stratified sample estimate of proportion" online returns many results for this topic. I copied the formulas for the estimate and variance out of this textbook,

Scheaffer, Mendenhall, Ott, & Gerow. (2012). Elementary Survey Sampling, 7th Ed.